# Cast to bool nullable of null value VS default value of bool nullable

Tags: c#, casting, default, nullable, anonymous-class

Is there any difference between those two ways to write the same thing?

`int? foo = GetValueOrDefault();`

```
var obj = new
{
    //some code...,
    bar = foo.HasValue ? foo > 0 : (bool?)null
}
```

VS

`int? foo = GetValueOrDefault();`

```
var obj = new
{
    //some code...,
    bar = foo.HasValue ? foo > 0 : default(bool?)
}
```

Comment: Quick ways of testing this sort of thing (much quicker than asking SO, in any case) are LINQPad and https://sharplab.io . As a guideline, if it compiles to the same IL there is no difference. If it compiles to different IL, there could still be no difference if it gets JIT-compiled to the same assembly.

Comment: @Jodrell: because that only works for your edited version of the question, which changes the semantics of the original, which is why I've rolled it back. In an anonymous object declaration you can't specify the type of the member explicitly, it must be derived from the expression.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you have a point, my bad. Although it may be moot. https://dotnetfiddle.net/JPohDD and https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+yAkIwJYB2ALgPzoBmA9v3QBedMACmvAIYBXADYcA3E0YA3KQCd0/AEYArOCPRtxAdxUEkzRgHobAZ34BbcegDG/CQDofAGhWMOppGAvxeABJS9gBqUnIyrjyh6AB86AAM6CDo1DqCcly0bPJyKgC+ylaMKupaunowRibmVZbWdo4u7p7iPl7+VYHBoqERUbHxiXyCqRlZYpKyCrn5heWVzDXB9RiizRYBHc6uHt5+AUFaI4JjMXEJ6EkzaZnZK/wFtBLS8hzrhMQysgykA===

Comment: @Jodrell: not entirely, in this context -- while `(bool?) null` and `default(bool?)` work from C# 2 onwards, `(bool?) default` needs C# 7.1. Not likely to be an issue in practice, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same. A `Nullable<bool>` is a struct and the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs) states:

> The default value of a struct is the value produced by setting all
> fields to their default value (§15.4.5).

Since a `Nullable<T>` has these two fields:

```
private bool hasValue; // default: false
internal T value;  // default value of T, with bool=false
```

So yes, using `default(bool?)` has the same effect as using `(bool?)null`, because `(bool?)null` is also a `Nullable<bool>` with `hasValue=false`(same as using `new Nullable<bool>()`).

Why you can assign `null` at all to a `Nullable<T>` which is a struct, so a value type? Well, that is compiler magic which is not visible in [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e).